# What is wrong with this laravel database query?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have the following query:

```
$posts = Post::with( 'comments' => function($c) {
    $c->orderBy('commentTimestamp', 'desc')->take(6);
})
             ->where('category_id', '=', $category->id)
             ->take(20);
```

I want it to get 20 posts and get the last 6 comments of each post. But it seems that the query gets only 6 comments starting from first post (for example, if every post has 10 comments, the query gets 6 comments from the first post and nothing from the other posts). What is wrong?

Comment: It's..... not easily translatable to an SQL query. On the SQL level, your basic workable methods are (1) do a query per post or (2) query for all comments at once, and limit per-post in userland code. Which makes the translation to Eloquent for you: (1) either omit the with, and define a method on post to get the top N (6) comments, or (2) query for all comments without limit, and define a method on post which only gives back the first N (6) of all the comments already stored in that post.

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the answer.